# Wrap Asynchronous Function Call In an NSOperation

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, asynchronous, nsoperation

I'm trying to use a function with a completion handler, called like this:

```
myFunc(completion: {(var1, var2) -> Void in
    // do something interesting with variables
})
```

My issue is that I need that to be dependent on other NSOperations and have dependencies that are NSOperations, so I need to wrap myFunc() in an NSOperation. How would I go about doing this?

I've started looking into subclassing NSOperation and implementing the asynchronous 'finished' flag, but it just seems like there should be an easier, more lightweight way to do this without a subclass, possibly using NSBlockOperation or NSInvocationOperation.

Comment: This question is pretty broad... so [start here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues) and if you run into trouble, you can come ask a more specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with AsyncOpKit. It allows you to mark an operation 'finished' after the internal asynchronous call is completed. Here is the example code with the function defined above

```
class MyFuncOperation: AsyncOperation {
    override main() {
        myFunc(completion: {(var1, var2) -> Void in
            // do something interesting with variables
            finish()
        })
    }
}
```

Then just use `MyFuncOperation` as you would any `NSOperation` subclass.

```
let operation = MyFuncOperation()
NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!.addOperation(operation)
```

https://cocoapods.org/pods/AsyncOpKit

Comment: OK... Thanks. The good part is the link to "AsyncOpKit", but I think just a little more explanation is due... Obviously you finally DO inherit from NSOperation (via AsyncOperation) and you DO override the "finished" thing somehow -- but how? My situation s a little harder, because I don't have a fun swift/Obj-C callback block with context. Just a nasty C-style call from Java to tell me something has finished... So I can't use this as is.